# add a new row to the top of UITableView while using core data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data

i have a textfield  where i enter a value and save it and retrieve them in a tableView.
the last item saved is shown at the bottom of the table view.
But i want it to be shown at the top of the table view.

i tried the following code but failed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   CoreDataOneAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
   NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = 
   [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:context];
   NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   [request setEntity:entityDesc];
    NSError *error;
    objects = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]retain];
    [request release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}



-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  [objects count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    labelOne = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 11, 110, 21)];
    labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 11, 70, 21)];

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelTwo];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelOne];

    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
    matches = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    labelOne.text = [matches valueForKey:@"name"];
    labelTwo.text = [matches valueForKey:@"amount"];

    NSArray *index = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:index withRowAnimation:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

//Saving

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
CoreDataOneAppDelegate  *appDelegate = 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = 
[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newContact;
newContact = [NSEntityDescription
              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee"
              inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newContact setValue:name.text forKey:@"name"];
[newContact setValue:amount.text forKey:@"amount"];
name.text = @"";
amount.text = @"";
//label
status.text = @"saved";
NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume you somewhere do `[objects addObject:newEntry]`. Change that to `[objects insertObject:newEntry atIndex:0]`.

Comment: i am very much new to xcode.so please dont mind i am asking u dumb questions.i didnt use [objects addObject:newEntry]. anywhere in my code.i have posted the remaining code too.please check and help!

Comment: The code you posted is all about the table view. But what about the code which is executed whenever the user enters something to the text field?

Comment: code updated!.but i wrote this code for saving in a different view controller.

Comment: ok, I see it's CoreData. I don't now much about that and in which order objects are fetched. I think you can change the order of results by setting sortDescriptors at you NSFetchRequest. I'm not sure how to tell the request to fetch newest first. Maybe sort by ID? Sorry.